# @Inject does not work while running junit tests

Tags: logging, mockito

I am injecting a logger (slf4j logger) into a class and using this in my method for which i have written junit tests.

eg

```
class A{

  @Inject
  Logger logger;


  public void methodA(){
    this.logger.info("helo logs");
    return true;
  }
}
```

now in the junit tests I am using Mockito

```
@InjectMocks
A obj;

public void testmethod(){
  boolean res = obj.methodA();
  Assert.assertEquals(true,res);
}
```

This is just a sample, this is present as a maven project. Now when I do clean install in maven all junit tests are run and I am getting a null pointer exception since logger is not injected.

Please tell me what can be done??

Comment: whn i comment all my logger statements then ther is no error while deplouing or running. however whne i insert loggers and when junit runs i am getting a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

put following code before @InjectMocks

```
@Mock
Logger logger;
```

`@Inject` only works with Spring or other Bean Containers. Mockito injects only `@Mocks` defined in your test class.